# Java List find equal item

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a class Heading:

```
public class Heading {
    // Some other members, methods etc.
    private String description;
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

I need to write a method that groups together all Headings with the same description and returns a Map which has Lists of Headings with the same description as the values in the map.

[Part of original question follows.  It's not clear to me (andybalaam) what is required to be in the keys of the map.]

> I need to create a method that iterates through the Heading List to find out if there is
>   Heading Object with the same description. At this point, i would like to copy all
>   the Heading Objects with the same description into another List and put 
>   this List into an 
>   HashMap < Integer , List < Heading > >
>   The method should return this HashMap that contains, for-each key, the List of Heading
>   Object with the same description.

Comment: Please learn how to enter code.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Just a hint, take a look at the `Comparable` interface, you'll need to use it if you want to use some of the built in functionality in your `Map`s and `List`s.

Comment: i apologize for the not well formatted code

Comment: @dante When you will have some particular problems - don't hesitate to ask then, describing what you're doing and what's the problem. Good luck.

Comment: dante what number do you want as the keys of the Map?

Comment: i want key integer start by zero and increase by one any time the method found a set of Heading with the same description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a map of description -> list of Heading.  You can't have a map of size-of-list -> list of Heading because you might have several lists with the same length, and you can only have one map entry with a given key.

```
public static Map<String, List<Heading>> sameDescs( List<Heading> input )
{
    Map<String, List<Heading>> ret = new HashMap<String, List<Heading>>();

    for( Heading heading : input )
    {
        if( ! ret.containsKey( heading.getDescription() ) )
        {
            ret.put( heading.getDescription(), new ArrayList<Heading>() );
        }
        ret.get( heading.getDescription() ).add( heading );
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You can print of the sizes of the lists like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<Heading> myList = new ArrayList<Heading>();
    myList.add( new Heading( "desc1" ) );
    myList.add( new Heading( "desc2" ) );
    myList.add( new Heading( "desc1" ) );

    Map<String, List<Heading>> result = sameDescs( myList );

    for( Map.Entry<String, List<Heading>> e : result.entrySet() ) {
        System.out.println( e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue().size() );
    }
}
```

Which produces output like this:

```
desc1:2
desc2:1
```